# How to fix "HTTP CONNECTION FAILED" error

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

I just updated my anaconda distribution using conda update --all. There were a few debug messages during the update but it otherwise finished successfully. However, now I can't update any packages. Any time I try, I now get this error:

[image]

I am working through a company proxy, but have verified that the proxy info in my .condarc file is accurate. I've also verified that anaconda.com is not blocked by my company. Additionally, I was previously able to update packages without this error. I get this error regardless of which package I try to update, or whether I specify a specific channel. Does anyone have any idea what this could be?

Here's my .condarc settings (excluding proxy information for obvious reasons):

ssl_verify: false

channel_priority: disabled

channels:

- defaults
- conda-forge

Here are the results of "conda info":

[image]

Any idea what the fix for this is?

Answer (score 0):

found the answer (sort of)! It’s something to do with urllib3. I reinstalled conda and pinned urllib3 to version 1.25.11, and now conda updates fine!